# For what example would Maekawa's algorithm allow out of timestamp order access to the critical section

Tags: distributed-systems, mutual-exclusion, critical-section

For what example would [Maekawa's algorithm](https://fr.coursera.org/lecture/cloud-computing-2/2-4-maekawas-algorithm-and-wrap-up-GMHYN) allow out of timestamp order access to the critical section. It is mentioned that ordering is not satisfied in Maekawa's algorithm. But in what scenario would this be true?

From my understanding, we will always have the queue at each process that follows FIFO and will ensure that whichever process requested access to critical seciton first, gets votes from the voting set first. Doesn't this satisfy ordering?